# get indicators outside of materialize carousel

Tags: html, css, materialize

It seems like when using carousel, the indicators are by default inside of the images.

How to make them outside, but always keep a fixed distance to the images no matter how you resize your browser?

In my example I set a static height to the carousel but then the indicators have different distance to the images, if you resize your browser.

I add `responsive-img` so the images scale.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 l6 black-text flow-text">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>text text text</li>
        <li>text text text</li>
        <li>text text text</li>
        <li>text text text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class=" col s12 l6 ">
    <div class="carousel carousel-slider">
        <div class="carousel-item ">
            <a href=" " target="_blank ">
                <img class="responsive-img " src="http://globalmedicalco.com/photos/globalmedicalco/1/3586.jpg " />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
            <a href=" " target="_blank ">
                <img class="responsive-img " src="http://globalmedicalco.com/photos/globalmedicalco/1/3586.jpg " />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
            <a href=" " target="_blank ">
                <img class="responsive-img " src="http://globalmedicalco.com/photos/globalmedicalco/1/3586.jpg " />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .carousel{
    height:520px !important;
  }
```

[I am the example](https://codepen.io/frostless/pen/VdEMPx)

The materialize version is Materialize v1.0.0-rc.2.

Comment: What effect exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek I want to have a fixed distance(e.g 10px ) between the images(rabit) and the indicators, no matter how to resize your screen. The indicators have to be outside of images. And I want the images to be responsive. The current problem is the carousel will not scale its height when the images scale their sizes.

Comment: That depends on images sizes, which we don't know before rendering the slider.

Comment: I know the size of the images. And if I add a class"responsive-img" it will scale according to the view port. I try to add something like `indicators{position:absolute;bottom:-20px}` it does not work. Once the indicators go beyond its container box it will disappear.

Comment: So you want indicators to stick to lower edge of images, right? But what if images have different height?

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek not the lower edge, that is the default. I want the indicators outside of the image, but keeping the same distance to the image. No matter how the image rescale.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to change the function in materialize.js
`_setCarouselHeight`

`this.$el.css('height', imageHeight + {variable distance}+ 'px');`